# Which is the correct way to to retrieve all the informations from a dbpedia page?

Tags: dbpedia

I am working with dbpedia. In my work, my program need to read a dbpedia json file like(http://dbpedia.org/data/Germany.json) and extract all the information as a key value pair, same as dbpedia page(http://dbpedia.org/page/Germany). But I am facing some problem. For example, if you see the json file(please use some json viewer to make it human readable.), if i want to get the language(search language in the file), you will see it is in the json array, so i have to extract that information from the Array. On the other hand, if you search seeAlso, then you will find that you have to go one level up and find the information. Further more , there are some information in the HTML page(http://dbpedia.org/page/Germany) but  that is not found in the metadata json
file(http://dbpedia.org/data/Germany.json). For example, "birthPlace" is in html page but not in the json file. I am totally confused that, how i will code that can read and store(as key value mapping) the data as like as seen in the html page.

Answer (score 0):

DBpedia data is organized by resource, where each "resource" is a page on Wikipedia and (presumably) a thing in the real world. Each resource is referred to with a URL. The JSON file contains a whole bunch of resources (such as http://dbpedia.org/resource/Opel_Kadett_C) that have some link with the resource you're interested in, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Germany. I think this is supposed to include all the information at http://dbpedia.org/page/Germany, but clearly some entries -- such as db:Anja_Kling -- are missing. I'm not sure why that is, but it might be a bug -- if you don't get a better answer here, you should try e-mailing your questions to the dbpedia-discussion mailing list at https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/dbpedia-discussion. Hope that helps!